# Trying to retrieve hashtags via TwitterOAuth returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api, twitter

Code snippet to retrieve tweets:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

require "config.php"; //Containing consumer key and consumer secret
require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

$query = array(
"q" => "#CM0677",
"count" => 5,
"result_type" => "recent"
);

$tweets = $connection->get('search/tweets', $query);

echo(json_encode($tweets));
?>
```

CODE SNIPPET TO APPEND TO HTML VIA JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //get the JSON data that is echoed out in the //call_twitter_API.php code
    $.getJSON("call_twitter_API.php",function(tweetdata) {
        $.each(tweetdata, function(i, tweet){
            $("#tweet-list").append("<li>" + tweet.text +"</li>");
        });
    })
})
```

HTML File contains a UL with the ID tweet-list

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to get it to actually return the hashtag tweets rather than just displaying 'undefined'